# List is scrolling while value is typed in dynamic TextField in ListView in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

The screen is scrolling while the text is entered into the text field and  I have used this `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding:false,` inside `Scaffold` to avoid screen resizing and the List is Dynamic with Textfield. How can I stop scrolling or resizing screen while editing dynamic `textfield`?

[image]

I have also resist physical scroll by adding `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` inside ListView.builder.

```
Container dynamciContainer(BuildContext context,double width,double height){
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder
        (
          itemCount:sfieldList.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          return dynamicItem(ctxt,width, height,sfieldList[index],index);
          }
      ),
    );
  }
```

TextField Item

```
 Container textFieldContainer(double width,Fieldlist field,int p){
    return Container(

      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[200], width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(45.0))),
         padding:EdgeInsets.only(top:width*0.009,bottom: width*0.009,left: width*0.05,right: width*0.00),
         child:  new TextField(
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'semibold',color: MyColors.colorPrimary),
        keyboardType:field.type=='STR'||field.type=='EMAIL'? TextInputType.text:TextInputType.number,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        decoration: InputDecoration(contentPadding:EdgeInsets.all(8.0),hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'semibold',color: MyColors.colorPrimary), border: InputBorder.none),
        onChanged: (String val) {
          enteredValue(field,val);
          setState(() {
            sfieldList[p].fieldvalue=val;
          });
        },),
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you please provide code for your dynamic text field in listview? Because "physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()" is working for static text fields in listview and when we try to scroll on the time of editing it's not allow me to scroll.

Comment: @android see my updated code.

Comment: i don't know why but your code is working for me :) i think its may be container issue

Comment: @android I have multiple lists on that screen .

Comment: do you mean nested listview? if yes then please post that code also. may be i can help you